# Copying a DVD in Yosemite

Tags: macos, software-recommendation

I am looking for software to copy a DVD home created without copy guard.  Roxio Toast stopped working after installing Yosemite

Answer (score 2):

You already have everything you need.

Open up disk utility, select the top filesystem under the DVD on the left side and create an image of it (CD/DVD master, is the format you should select, if I recall correctly) and save it to the location of your choice.

When it is done the DVD image will remaim in the list in the Disk Utility window. Eject the source DVD and insert your blank. Select the DVD image in the Disk Utility window and click on Burn Image (if it is not in the toolbar, it should be a menu choice).

Not as easy as Toast but easy enough...

Comment: [ScreenShot 1](http://i.stack.imgur.com/68tSN.jpg) [Screenshot 2](http://i.stack.imgur.com/KETpA.jpg) @Steve Chambers Nope. Those options do not appear in Yosemite, Disk Utility, when I select any DVD (no copy protection) and want to copy to any hard drive so I can make an .ISO or similar file to burn later onto a blank DVD. **Please give more info on how to copy FROM a DVD, TO a hard drive, and then onto a blank DVD, simply using *Yosemite Disk Utility*?** I see no option that works here... Help, anyone?

Comment: You missed the point "create an image of it"  The functionality can be found in ScreenShot 1 inside the toolbar, named "New Image". Choose option "CD/DVD Master" and go on as described

Answer (score 1):

Roxio says they will issue an update (one of these days)...

http://forums.support.roxio.com/topic/104311-tt12-on-yosemite/

However, with it being [March 2015 and still no update](http://www.roxio.com/enu/products/toast/#tab=3), it might be costing more money to re-engineer the app than they can afford to invest based on sales projections.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few options for *copying* and *burning* DVDs. For copying DVDs a few options are: [HandBrake](https://handbrake.fr), a free and open source option. Another DVD copying software is [MDRP](http://www.macdvdripperpro.com/) (Mac DVD Ripper Pro) which gives you 5 free DVD rips before purchase is required. One more option if the other two don't work or don't suit you is [RipIt](http://thelittleappfactory.com/ripit/) by the Little App Factory which gives you 10 free DVD copy's also.

A free app for *burning* DVDs with video or just audio on your Mac is [Burn](http://burn-osx.sourceforge.net/Pages/English/home.html) which I have used to create a home movie recently and works well. Hopefully one of those will work what you need!